# Vuetify Autocomplete, accept value outside list

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify autocomplete component that displays a list of names that the user selects from. I would like a fallback case where if the user enters something not on the list that value is still accepted.
Here is my code:

```
<v-autocomplete
v-model="model.name"
:items="users"
placeholder="Enter your name"
no-data-text="Name not Found"
clearable
></v-autocomplete>
```

Where the value of the autocomplete is bound to a data variable and the items is an array coming from my server. The autocomplete component is part of a larger form that accepts submissions of data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try using `v-combobox` instead of `v-autocomplete`. `v-combobox` accept values entered by user that do not exist within provided items.

src: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer but did not suit my use case as it returns the entire object (As per documentation). If I had more time I could have got it to work but do not as of right now. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5479#issuecomment-665695066 probably this snippet will help you out.